# solucion a este problema

Tags: python

```
Numero_hermanos=int(input("introduce el numero de hermanos"))
print(Numero_hermanos)

Salario_familia=int(input("introduce el salario familiar anual"))
print(Salario_familia)

if Distancia_escuela>40 and Numero_hermanos>2 Salario_familia<=20000:

    print("tienes derecho a beca")

else:

    print("no tienes derecho a beca")
```

> File "condicionales ejemplo 5.py", line 11
>       if Distancia_escuela>40 and Numero_hermanos>2 Salario_familia<=20000:
>                                                                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ***Repl Closed***

Comment: tienes 3 condiciones a cumplir pero entre la segunda y tercera te falta un operador lógico del tipo AND u OR

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos problemas, la falta de una condición o token que acepte el `if` y uno próximo que es que no declaras la variable `Distancia_escuela`, sólo la evalúas sin haberla definido.

```
Numero_hermanos=int(input("introduce el numero de hermanos: "))
print(Numero_hermanos)

Salario_familia=int(input("introduce el salario familiar anual: "))
print(Salario_familia)

################
#  A pesar de que el error que se te muestra es sobre la falta de una condicion o un
#+ token valido, otro proximo error es de la la variable "Distancia_escuela"
#+ que no estas declarando, por lo que necesitas hacerlo.
Distancia_escuela = int(input("introduce la distancia de tu escuela: "))
print(Distancia_escuela)
################

#-----------------------------------------------
#                                              |  Aqui esta el error, en tu codigo
#                                              |+ original te hizo falta una condicion
#                                              |+ yo puse un "and".
if Distancia_escuela>40 and Numero_hermanos>2 and Salario_familia<=20000:

    print("tienes derecho a beca")

else:

    print("no tienes derecho a beca")
```

Comment: Si, no puso la declaración de esa variable en el ejemplo, pero su error es de sintaxis, no de variable no definida. Saludos.

Comment: Por eso aclaré como "uno próximo". El de sintaxis también lo abordé tanto en el código como en el resumen inicial, de hecho fue el primero que abordé.

Comment: Si la declaro o no solo el sabe, pero esta muy bien que lo señales.